# what is the limit definition of second order derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I want to prove that if $f(x)$ has second order derivative than it should given by:
$$f''(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)}{h^2}$$ but I can not prove this. So I try to write that definition of the derivative:

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
f''(x)= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}\quad(1)
\end{equation}

From here I expand: $$f'(x+h)= \lim_{c\to0} \frac{f(x+h+c)-f(x+h)}{c}$$ and similarly for $f'(x)$ in $(1)$. So then I substitute it into $(1)$:

\begin{align}
f''(x)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\lim_{c\to0} \frac{f(x+h+c)-f(x+h)}{c}-\lim_{c\to0} \frac{f(x+c)-f(x)}{c}}{h} \\= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\lim_{c\to0} [\frac{f(x+h+c)-f(x+h)}{c}- \frac{f(x+c)-f(x)}{c}]}{h} \\= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\lim_{c\to0} [\frac{f(x+h+c)-f(x+h)- f(x+c)-f(x)}{c}]}{h}
\end{align}
What I am trying to do is to prove is that $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\lim_{c\to0} [\frac{f(x+h+c)-f(x+h)- f(x+c)-f(x)}{c}]}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)}{h^2}$$ but I could not do it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/210264/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/491248/42969

Comment: I would take $c \rightarrow h$, instead of $c \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Notice that this is not a limit *definition* of the second derivative; it's possible for this limit to exist even if the second derivative does not.  (Example: $ f ( x ) = x ^ 3 \sin ( 1 / x ) $ with $ f ( 0 ) = 0 $, at $ x = 0 $.)  But if $ f ' ' ( x ) $ *does* exist, then it must equal this limit; that's all that you can expect to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $h$ and $c$ both approach $0$ at the same time, so you could replace both with a variable $k$ approaching $0.$

This means that $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\lim_{c\to0} [\frac{f(x+h+c)-f(x+h)- f(x+c)-f(x)}{c}]}{h} = \lim_{k\to0} \frac{f(x+2k)-2f(x+k)-f(x)}{k^2}.$$

Comment: This kind of thing is dangerous; for example, if I have $ \lim \limits _ { x \to 0 } \lim \limits _ { y \to 0 } \frac { 2 x y } { x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 } $, then this is $ 0 $, but if I change it to $ \lim \limits _ { k \to 0 } \frac { 2 k k } { k ^ 2 + k ^ 2 } $, then this is $ 2 $.